# Why can't I clear float when using BFC feature on body?

Tags: html, css, css-float

On other tags, using BFC can clear the float, why the body is not available.
As expected, add overflow: hidden on the body to form a BFC, which can achieve the effect of clearing the float, but this is not the case?

```css
div.f {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed skyblue;
}

.p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <div class="p">
        <div class="f"></div>
        <div class="f"></div>
    </div> -->

    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because overflow has a special behavior when applied to body element and it get propagated to html element instead. You need to add  `overflow:auto` to html to avoid this:

```css
div.f {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed skyblue;
}

html {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="f"></div>
<div class="f"></div>
```

> UAs must apply the `overflow-*` values set on the root element to the viewport. However, when the root element is an [HTML] `html` element (including XML syntax for HTML) whose overflow value is visible (in both axes), and that element has a body element as a child, user agents must instead apply the `overflow-*` values of the first such child element to the viewport. **The element from which the value is propagated must then have a used overflow value of visible**. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation)</sup>

So you body element will have again `overflow:visible` after the propagation

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,This is the answer I want most。

Answer (score 1):

To have it working on the body, you can use [`display:flow-root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context#Using_display_flow-root), I believe this is have to do with how the width of the content affects the body display/render, and by adding `display:flow-root` it will clear floated tag inside it.

```css
div.f {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

body {
  display: flow-root;
  border: 1px dashed skyblue;
}

.p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--<div class="p">
        <div class="f">AAAA</div>
        <div class="">test</div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="f"></div>
    <div class="f"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I would like to ask, overflow: hidden is invalid for body?

Comment: Glad to help, for your question, its not invalid, you can use but the thing is it will not create BFC on the body, and please consider  [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :)